# Azure mac hosted agent : Acquiring an agent from the cloud: Request queue position information is unavailable

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent, azure-devops-pipelines

i just notices that even though i have a pool of 10 hosted agent in azure which are free and idle
I'm waiting a long time to execute the build job and I see this msg for a long period of time:

```
Acquiring an agent from the cloud:
Request queue position information is unavailable.
Job preparation parameters
ContinueOnError: False
TimeoutInMinutes: 30
CancelTimeoutInMinutes: 5
Expand:
  MaxConcurrency: 0
  ########## System Pipeline Decorator(s) ##########

  Begin evaluating template 'system-pre-steps.yml'
Evaluating: eq('true', variables['system.debugContext'])
Expanded: eq('true', Null)
Result: False
Evaluating: resources['repositories']['self']
Expanded: Object
Result: True
Evaluating: not(containsValue(job['steps']['*']['task']['id'], '6d15af64-176c-496d-b583-fd2ae21d4df4'))
Expanded: not(containsValue(Object, '6d15af64-176c-496d-b583-fd2ae21d4df4'))
Result: True
Evaluating: resources['repositories']['self']['checkoutOptions']
Result: Object
Finished evaluating template 'system-pre-steps.yml'
********************************************************************************
Template and static variable resolution complete. Final runtime YAML document:
steps:
- task: 6d15af64-176c-496d-b583-fd2ae21d4df4@1
  inputs:
    repository: self


  MaxConcurrency: 0
Parent pipeline used these runtime parameters
Folderpath : "ios-client"
FolderCompile : "dir"
```

what is the problem?

Comment: You should probably be more specific about what "long period of time" means.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this issue stably? Could it be a network crack.

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT
it fixed when i canceled the job and restart it
im using macOS latest  , do you have problems with it ?

Comment: No I don't have problem with it. According to your shared info, it looks like a network crack.  Glad to hear issue solved. You could *move the comment to below answer and mark it*, in case someone else faces this same error message.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Cancel & restart is not fixing it for me. I've been waiting for 25 min now. still in queue

Comment: I deleted my pipeline. And created it with the same yml file. Now it is working fine. Not sure if Azure is the way to go for reliable CI builds